# Can anyone explain on how to draw this shape?

Tags: geometry

[Click here for the shape of the lenses and frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPvoC.png)

Can anyone explain on how to draw the shape of the lenses and frames?

Thank you if you answered my question.

Comment: Excellent completely mathematical question! First observe shape of the lenses are flip symmetric and approximately circular, so we can approximate them to arbitrary approximation $n$ as curves with equation $\sum_{i=2}^n a_i x^i + \sum_{i=2}^n b_i y^i = 1$. Now you just have to find the coefficents of best fit $a_i$ and $b_i$ using the axiom of choice, or you can compute the inverse of the respective $i \times i$ matrix and find it's determinant. Very trivial matters, I leave it to you.

Comment: With "draw", do you mean with pen and paper?

Comment: Probably, yeah..

Comment: Those were most likely modelled with [B-splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline). You can find implementations on-line. MS Paint even has one built-in, though it's pretty crappy. You'll have to play around to find the right support points to get that shape, though.